# Some Angular(V4.2.5) animation not working in iOS 12.2 Beta

Tags: javascript, ios, angular

Currently my application, some angular animation is not working.

Following stuff i'm doing in current app,

- Creating a cordovaviewcontroller instance in background and supplying start page link. And just have this instance in property and not rendering this view controller in screen.
- Few angular resource are loaded in background itself in the cordova instance which i created in step 1, to improve the webview loading performance.
- Durning some button action, I'm opening Viewcontroller with cordovaviewcontroller view as subview and rending specific angular screen with animation.
- Everything working fine <12.2 beta.
- In 12.2 beta, some of the angular animation are not working properly.
- We tried to remove the anugular animation and tried. After that, angular screen rendering properly without animation.
- One more step also I tried, instead of initializing cordova in background, created cordova instance in foreground and rendered viewcontroller, now also everything working fine.

Is loading web stuff in background, causing issue? I really need that background loading part for the performance.

Any help is appreciated.